# Are there any theorems about the existence of feasible solutions to the Mixed-Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) problem?

Tags: integer-programming, programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am just wondering if there are any theorems about the existence of feasible solutions to the Mixed-Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP) problem. For example:

- Theorems about *sufficient* conditions ensuring the existence of feasible solutions in a MINLP problem;
- Theorems about *necessary* conditions ensuring the existence of feasible solutions in a MINLP problem.

**Furthermore, I would really appreciate it if you could tell me the solvers (please tell me if they are free) that can find feasible solutions to a given MINLP problem.**